# my transcend external hdd (500GB) works on Ubuntu but not on Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu-netbook, external-hdd

I have Transcend 500GB external hard disk. I recently switched from Windows7 to Ubuntu. Before everything was working fine, but now as I have my project files on external hard disk, I used MountManager to mount my hdd on ubuntu. But now my hdd is only detected on ubuntu on my laptop(not sure if will be detected on other laptop/computer with ubuntu).

When I try to use it with Windows, nothing happens at all, not detected, not even in Disk Management of Windows, not a single sign of my hdd. But when i tried Windows7 setup disk, I found my hdd in advanced tools.

I have very valuable and confidential data in my hdd so don't wana format it, Any good idea to make my hdd fine on any device????

Output of "sudo fdisk -l"

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000983fd

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       38531   309492736   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           38531       38914     3076097    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           38531       38914     3076096   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00058e44

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       60801   488384001    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

/dev/sdb1 is my external hdd

BTW, Window Setup can detect my hdd not in normal view(default display of hdd available), it only detects only when I use Advanced Options...

Comment: How is it formatted?

Comment: it was ntfs format

Comment: You say it was, so what is it now?

Comment: i am not very good in linux so not sure for everything, but now its showing "ntfs-3g" and in SystemMonitor's File System's tab its showing "fuseblk" type

Comment: With the drive connected in Ubuntu, Can you supply the output of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: added output for "sudo fdisk -l" in this question above...

Comment: since windows setup tools can detect it I guess there is some problem with your windows installation. Try the hard disk in other computer with windows. If it detected correctly just reinstall windows and recover ubunutu later. :)

Comment: i will try it...

Comment: When you open Disk Management, do you see the drive listed?

Comment: no, its not listed there

Comment: Is the *disk* listed in the lower pane?

Comment: which lower pane?

Answer (score 1):

Oh,I found the problem. in your summary it says it is partitioned as HPFS/NTFS. 
Did you partition it in Ubuntu? I had the same error. It isn't detected by Windows since I partitioned it using Ubuntu. Backup all your data. And then format it as NTFS in Windows. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If You formated using ubuntu note the drive may not work well on windows especialy If you used FAT, FAT16 You may need to back up your data on ubuntu format using NFTS then restore the data